# Crontab won't execute shell script

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task

I tried to configure crontab to execute a shell script every day.
When executed manually, the file works well. Unfortunately, crontab won't execute it.

Here's my shell file:

```
#! bin/bash

# GENERAL properties
BASE_DIR=/opt/XXX-1.0
# JOB properties
JOBS_DIR=$BASE_DIR/jobs

#find all main etl jobs and execute them
cd $JOBS_DIR
find . -name '*mainrun.sh' -exec {} \;
```

And here's my crontab

```
10 14 * * * /bin/sh /opt/XXX-1.0/jobs/jobs.sh
```

Any ideas on what could be preventing me from executing it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen a /bin/sh in a crontab like that.
Why aren't you using a shebang at the start of your file like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Is the file itself executable for the crontab user that is executing it?

```
chmod +x /opt/XXX-1.0/jobs/jobs.sh
```

Comment: The file is executable. Thanks for helping, I actually made a typo in my filename in the shell script... Works fine now, lol.. (shame)